# Adding points and grade curve to an array of grades

Tags: java

I can't figure out how to output the gradecurve and added points grades passing from the methods to the print statements. I keep getting formatting Java errors. I asked my professor and he doesn't give me any true hints to fix this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GradeReview 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
     String nameOfFile;

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter name of the file: ");
  nameOfFile = input.nextLine();

  try 
  {
   input = new Scanner(new File(nameOfFile));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
  {
   System.err.println(" File not found.");
   System.exit(0);
  }

  int size = 0;

  while(input.hasNextLine())
  {
   input.nextLine();
   size++;
  }

  input.close();
  input = new Scanner(new File(nameOfFile));


  double[] score = new double[size];
  while(input.hasNextLine())
  {
input.nextLine();
 }


  input.close();


  double number = 0;
  double addScore = 0;


    //Array of grades 
    double[] gradeScore = new double[] {87.5, 47.9, 70.0, 91.6, 67.8, 83.3, 75.0, 96.0, 55.0,
      96.0, 54.7, 73.7, 60.0, 64.0 };




    //Output for lowest, highest, and average grades 
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Grade Summary");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Lowest Score: " + GetLowest(gradeScore));  
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Highest Score: " + GetHighest(gradeScore));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Average Score: %,.1f", + GetAverage(gradeScore));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Curve grade: %,.1f", GetCurve(gradeScore, number));
    System.out.printf("Added Points: %,.1f", GetPoints(gradeScore, addScore));

     //Set variables to get the number of each grade
     int gradeA = 0;
     int gradeB = 0;
     int gradeC = 0; 
     int gradeD = 0;
     int gradeF = 0;


           for (int i = 0; i < gradeScore.length; i++)
           {
          //Begin if statement for finding number of each grade 
            if (gradeScore[i] >= 90.0)
            {
             gradeA++;
            }
            if (gradeScore[i] >= 80.0 && gradeScore[i] <= 90.0)
           {
             gradeB++;
           } 
            if(gradeScore[i] >= 70.0 && gradeScore[i] <= 80.0)
           {
             gradeC++; 
           }
            if(gradeScore[i] >= 60.0 && gradeScore[i] <= 70.0)
           {
             gradeD++; 
           }
            if(gradeScore[i] < 60.0)
           {
             gradeF++; 
           }

           }//End if statement and for loop

    //Output of how many students got each grade        
    System.out.println("Grade A:  " + gradeA);
    System.out.println("Grade B:  " + gradeB);
    System.out.println("Grade C:  " + gradeC);
    System.out.println("Grade D:  " + gradeD);
    System.out.println("Grade F:  " + gradeF);  

}


    //Method for finding the lowest grade in the array
    public static double GetLowest(double[] myArray) 
    {

 double lowest = myArray[0];

 for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++)
 {
   if (myArray [i] < lowest)
   {
     lowest = myArray [i];

   }
 }
 return lowest;
  }
   //End of lowest method


    //Method for finding the highest grade in the array
    public static double GetHighest(double[] myArray) 
    {

 double highest = myArray[0];

 for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++)
 {
   if (myArray [i] > highest)
   {
     highest = myArray [i];

   }
 }
 return highest;
  }
   //End of highest method


   //Method for finding the average grade in the array 
   public static double GetAverage (double[] myArray)
   {
     double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i< myArray.length; i++)
    {
      total = total + myArray[i];
    }

    double average = total / myArray.length;


    return average;
   }
    //End of average method


   public static double[] GetCurve(double[] myArray, double curve) 
   {

  double []number = new double[myArray.length];
  for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++)
  {
    number[i] = myArray[i] * 1.05;
  }

  return number;

 }

 public static double[] GetPoints(double[]score, double points) 
 {
  double [] addScore = new double [score.length];
  for( int i = 1; i < score.length; i++)
  {
   addScore[i] = score[i] + points;
  }

  return addScore;
 }










  }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a gradecurve? I'm not entirely sure what that is. What's an expected input, and the output as a result of that input?

Comment: The second to last method in the code shows the array being multiplied by 1.05. I need output for that.

Comment: Also I noticed in your `"Finding num of each grade"` section you might end up with an incorrect expected output. For example `gradeScore[I] >= 90` so it's going to grab anything 90+, but on the next check it's `gradeScore[I] <= 90` which isn't too much of a problem but you don't need that `<=` operator, simply use `<` operator.

Comment: I want to output the array of grades thats called "gradeScore"  multiplied by 1.05. The output result of that. I just realized I can't do anything with the addPoints method unless I ask the user to enter how many points to add to the grades.

Answer (score 0):

Your GetCurve and GetPoints methods are returning arrays, but you are attempting to print single values. If they should return arrays, then you should wrap your print statements in for loops. Also, throughout your code, make sure that arrays are indexed from 0 to array.length-1.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but very broad. Can you provide some examples for him codebod?

Comment: So if I put my print statement in the for loop as:     System.out.printf("Curve grade: %,.1f", (number));

Answer (score 0):

Okay there are a couple of things wrong here. I'll attempt to point out the best that I can.

#### Conditional Checking

```
int i = 0;

//This works but it's an important logic concern to notice.
if ( i <= 1 ) { //Do Something }
else if ( i >= 1 ) { //Do Something }

//This does the exact same thing as above
if ( i <= 1 ) { //Do Something }
else if (i > 1 ) { //Do Something }
```

The reason that it does the same thing is that conditionals are checked from top to bottom in 99% of all languages. Meaning if your input is `1` then the first conditional will ALWAYS return `true`. However; if it is `2` then the second conditional will return `true`. Notice that in that block of code, the second conditional `else if` WILL NEVER return true for `1` because it is checked and returned on the first conditional.

#### Returning values from arrays

```
double[] curve = new double[] ( 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 );

for (int i = 0; i < curve.Length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Curve Element: " + curve[i]);
}
```

You cannot simply print out an entire array of values, you need to get each individual array element and print that or condense it down to one line. I'm not sure if your instructor is looking for an array or some calculation on the array to return a singular value.

#### forLoopsFTW()

```
for (int value : intArray) { //Do something with value }
for (i = 0; i < someLength; i++) { //Do something like someLength[i] }
```

These are the two common ways to loop through collections (Arrays). Currently you're using something like for `(i = 1; i < someNumber; i++)` which means you're going to miss the first element every time.

ALWAYS loop using `0` based indexing. You'll find out later on that there are tons of built-in methods that start with `0` and if you don't get a grasp on it early, you're going to learn very quickly what `Index out of bounds` errors are.